# Error in Web.config for MicrosoftAppPassword

Tags: botframework

Yesterday I had developed the bot application by using Cognitive Services Emotion APIs Services.After I deploy, the error occur in MicrosoftAppPassword.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try to generate a new app password for your bot at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com; there are occasional passwords that it currently generates that are invalid characters in XML strings.